# How would the existing processes in the session learn about and acquire the controlling terminal, just acquired by the session leader?

Tags: c, linux, terminal, process

In the first scenario,  a process calls `setsid()` to start a new session and become its leader, and calls `open()` to connect to a controlling terminal. Then the session leader goes on to `fork()` child processes, and the children will inherit the file descriptor to the controlling terminal.

In the second scenario,  if a session already has multiple processes and but has no controlling terminal, and then the leader creates a connection to a controlling terminal,  what about the other processes in the session:

- how would the other processes in the session learn that the session has a controlling terminal and
- how could they open the controlling terminal as a file descriptor?

Thanks.

Originated from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446207/for-a-process-what-are-the-differences-between-a-controlling-terminal-and-non-c

Comment: I wonder if the answer to this question might help with context (or as a clarification) to your other questions:  _Can children of a parent process (that initially has no controlling terminal) inherit the terminal that their parent process subsequently connects with?_.  Then: _If so, how?_

Comment: Yes, you rephrased my question correctly.

Comment: Conversation that dances around your questions _[here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/12101)_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The controlling terminal is described in a lot of documentation as a property of an entire session, but it's really a property of each individual process, which is inherited from parent to child in `fork`.  A process has to be a session leader to attach itself to a controlling tty, but any process can detach from its controlling tty, if it has one, with the `TIOCNOTTY` ioctl.  So the system is set up to handle processes that are in a session but not attached to a controlling tty.

In your "second scenario", processes that the session leader forked before attaching to a controlling tty do *not* get attached to that tty along with it.  This means that they are not entirely part of the session, in the same way that processes that have detached from the controlling tty are not entirely part of the session: they can't be put into the foreground with `tcsetpgrp`, they cannot open `/dev/tty`, they don't receive `SIGHUP` if the controlling tty hangs up, etc.  Processes that the session leader forks after it attaches a controlling tty, on the other hand, will inherit it as usual.

(As a general rule, in Unix, operations that manipulate the calling process's state *never* have any effect on any other process, even if it seems like they ought to; also as a general rule, when we say such and such is inherited over a `fork`, we mean that piece of state is *copied* into the child, not shared between parent and child.  An important exception is "open file description"s, which *are* shared.  If you have a regular file open in a process that forks, and the child calls `lseek` on its inherited file descriptor, the parent will see the seek pointer move.)